# Are there any random variable $X$ and measurable function $g$ such that $\mathbb{E} [g(X)]=\mathbb{E}[Xg(X)]=0$ while $g(X)\ne 0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

As titled. I was going through some problems related to the relation between uncorrelatedness and indepedence, and reached a situation where the existence of such RV and function would be nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely. If $X$ is uniform in $[0,1]$, we have
$$\mathbb E[X^n]=\frac{1}{n+1},$$
so
$$\mathbb E[aX^3+bX^2+cX]=\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{2}+d.$$
Let's try to find $(a,b)$ for which $g(X)=aX^2+bX+c$ works. We want
$$0=\mathbb E[g(X)]=\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}+c$$
and
$$0=\mathbb E[Xg(X)]=\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{2}.$$
These are three equations in two unknowns, so they have a nontrivial solution.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be any symmetric random variable with finite third moment such that $X^{2}$ is not  a constant and $g(x)=x^{2}+a$ where $a =-EX^{2}$. Then $Eg(X)=0$ and $EXg(X)=EX^{3}+aEX=0+0=0$. Specific example: $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you! One thing is that although this works well for most of the symmetric random variables, it does not work for a Rademacher (or a constant multiple of a Rademacher).

Comment: @uuddlrlrb4 Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.